# Laravel follow button uncaught request failed code 500

Tags: laravel, axios, http-status-code-500

i am following a tutorial and i got to a point where to make a "follow" button like instagram but for my case was a "support me now" nothing is different just the name but i getting every time the

```
"app.js:699 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (app.js:699)
    at settle (app.js:960)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:168)"
```

my code so far, show.blade.php:

```
                <div>
                    <a class="float-left pb-4" href="#">Add New Images</a>
                    <support-button user-id="{{ $post->user->id }}"></support-button>
                </div>
```

POST controller:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function supporters()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

USER Controller:

```
                 public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}

public  function supporting()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}


public function fundraising()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Fundraising::class);
}
```

my support button vue.js:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="float-right pb-4 linksstyle" @click="supportUser"><i class="fa fa-heart pr-2"></i>Support Me Now</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['userId'],

        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },

        methods: {
            supportUser() {
               axios.post('/support/' + this.userId)
                        .then(response => {
                            alert(response.data);
                        });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and last but not least this is the SupportsController:

```
class SupportsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(User $user)
    {
        return $user->username;
    }
}
```

for my roote:

```
Route::post('support/{user}', 'SupportsContoller@store');
```

i am really hoping if someone could help me at this point as i am new to Laravel and i am building my own website using tutorials but at this point i am really stuck thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see what was the error in browsers Network tab for errors like 500 or when Axios calls. Error description in Console tabs is mostly useful for the JS errors.

Comment: yes that's the error that i have got, is there more to it that i can find? thanks